# Summing up numeric values of two textboxes and showing it in real time in third textbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a method which I will put into `textchanged` or `keypress` event. In the method I am parsing values from textboxes to `int` and then give it to the method so it will add up those values and returns them as a string.
But when I delete the content of the textbox while it's running so I can use different values it acts like a string not a value and throws out `System.Format exeption` that the method got different data types.

This is the calling of the method which throws the error :

```
vys = Addup(Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text), 
            Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value)).ToString();

label1.Text = vys;
```

Comment: Use something like `int.TryParse()` to check whether your conversion is possible before doing it? Before calling your `Addup()` method.

Comment: Validate the input of the checkboxes and show an error message if it is not an int. You could use method int.TryParse. This method returns false when the parsing is not successful. If the value is false show error message and don't execute the method.

Comment: But are string allowed in the text box, in the first place?

Comment: And don't you check if the textBox3.Text is just space or Nothing before trying to convert it? For sum it's not an issue but when you change to multiplication..

Answer (score 0):

When working with *user input* we should *validate* it. E.g. what if user just *clear* `textBox12`? Yes, since *empty text* is **not** a *valid integer* `Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)` will throw `System.Format exeption`.

Let's validate with a help of `TryParse`:

```
  if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out var v3) &&
      int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out var v2) &&
      numericUpDown1.Value >= int.MinValue && numericUpDown1.Value <= int.MaxValue) {
    // All three values are valid integers
    // The result will be Decimal, that's why we can skip 
    // IntegerOverflowException prevention.
    // Order matters: 0m + 2_000_000_000 + 2_000_000_000 = 4_000_000_000m
    //                2_000_000_000 + 2_000_000_000 + 0m - Exception (overflow)
    label1.Text = (numericUpDown1.Value + v3 + v2).ToString();  
  }
  else {
    // At least one value is not a valid Int32
    label1.Text = "???";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. There is some more stuff, that i need to work out, but this really helps a lot.